# How can i quick find and replace with regular expression Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2010, replace

How can i use regex on this case ?

I want to find this :

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal2" Text="<%$ Resources: Resource, Admin_HeaderInfo%>" runat="server" />
<asp:Literal ID="Literal3" Text="<%$ Resources: Resource, Admin_ContentInfo%>" runat="server" />
..
..
```

and want to replace

```
<%= GetTranslate("Admin_HeaderInfo"); %>
<%= GetTranslate("Admin_ContentInfo"); %>
..
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:

`<asp:Literal ID=".+?" Text="<%\$ Resources: Resource, (.+?)%>" runat="server" />`

Replace with

```
<%= GetTranslate("$1"); %>
```

Comment: thx but i edited it now , can you look at again plz, and how can learn regex what your advice ?

Comment: Visual studio gives an error on ":" char (unknown operator).But this regex works fine in regex tester.